# Lag values and differences in pandas dataframe with missing quarterly data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, financial

Though Pandas has time series functionality, I am still struggling with dataframes that have incomplete time series data.

See the pictures below, the lower picture has complete data, the upper has gaps. Both pics show correct values. In red are the columns that I want to calculate using the data in black. Column `Cumm_Issd` shows the accumulated issued shares during the year, `MV` is market value.

I want to calculate the issued shares per quarter (`IssdQtr`), the quarterly change in Market Value (`D_MV_Q`) and the `MV` of last year (`L_MV_Y`).

See for underlying cvs data this [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2727414/example_soverflow_gaps.csv) for the full data and this [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2727414/example_soverflow_orig.csv) for the gapped data. There are two firms `1020180` and `1020201`.

However, when I try Pandas `shift` method it fails when there are gaps, try yourself using the csv files and the code below. All columns (`DiffEq, Dif1MV, Lag4MV`) differ - for some quarters - from `IssdQtr, D_MV_Q, L_MV_Y`, respectively.

Are there ways to deal with gaps in data using Pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

dfg = pd.read_csv('example_soverflow_gaps.csv',low_memory=False)
dfg['date']     = pd.to_datetime(dfg['Period'], format='%Y%m%d')
dfg['Q']        = pd.DatetimeIndex(dfg['date']).to_period('Q')
dfg['year']     = dfg['date'].dt.year

dfg['DiffEq']    = dfg.sort_values(['Q']).groupby(['Firm','year'])['Cumm_Issd'].diff()
dfg['Dif1MV']    = dfg.groupby(['Firm'])['MV'].diff(1)
dfg['Lag4MV']    = dfg.groupby(['Firm'])['MV'].shift(4)
```

Gapped data:

[image]

Full data:

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do with you calculations when there are gaps? Is `pd.DataFrame.fillna(method='ffill')` an option for you?

Comment: The gaps should be NaN

Comment: Maybe you can get away with `dfg.groupby(['Firm'])['MV']..fillna(np.nan).shift(4)` then. `pandas` automatically propagates NaN values in operations like this one.

Comment: Was resample() considered here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the basic problem by using a merge. First, create a variable that shows the lagged date or quarter. Here we want last year's MV (4 quarters back):

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import QuarterEnd 
dfg['lagQ'] = dfg['date'] + QuarterEnd(-4)
```

Then create a data-frame with the keys (Firm and date) and the relevant variable (here MV).

```
lagset=dfg[['Firm','date', 'MV']].copy()
lagset.rename(columns={'MV':'Lag_MV', 'date':'lagQ'}, inplace=True)
```

Lastly, merge the new frame into the existing one:

```
dfg=pd.merge(dfg, lagset,  on=['Firm', 'lagQ'], how='left')
```

Comment: Alternatively follow this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664877/pandas-equivalent-of-oracle-lead-lag-function